# The wrong value (None) is displayed when I call a variable defined in a previous function

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I made a program of a Poker game and I started with a function for creating the entire deck, and another function for shuffling it. They both worked just fine. I was able to print out the deck and shuffled deck. But in another function '**hand()**', I tried to make a it a function that gives the player his first two cards, using a variable dictionary **deckshuffle** from the previous deck of shuffled cards. But it shows an error saying that the list index is out of range, so I decided to call the dictionary **deckshuffle** to see what it's value was, and it showed two empty curly brackets, instead of a whole dictionary full of shuffled cards

```
<ipython-input-57-462bc7e6b87f> in hand()
     28 def hand():
     29     liste = list(deckshuffle.items())
---> 30     playerhand.update({liste[0][0]:liste[0][1]})
     31     playerhand.update({liste[1][0]:liste[1][1]})
     32     liste.pop(0)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code-

```
deckvalues = {}


def cards():
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deckvalues.update({rank+' of '+suit: values[rank]})
    return deckvalues


def shufflecards():
    lis = list(deckvalues.items())
    random.shuffle(lis)
    deckshuffle = dict(lis)
    deckshuffle = deckshuffle
    return deckshuffle

playerhand = {}
dealerhand = {}
def hand():
    liste = list(deckshuffle.items())
    playerhand.update({liste[0][0]:liste[0][1]})
    playerhand.update({liste[1][0]:liste[1][1]})
    liste.pop(0)
    liste.pop(0)
```

Comment: `liste = list(deckshuffle.items())` in the function `hand` shouldn't even work, because `deckshuffle` is not in the scope of that function. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so for this one there are a few things that I would recommend. The first one being that you are casting it to a list multiple times which shouldn't be needed because your functions are returning list to begin with.

The second portion of this is you are not calling your global variable of deckvalues when you are making your hand. You do not want to do exactly what Roman said but close.

Here is what I would recommend:

```
   deckvalues = shufflecards() #This will load your shuffled deck values into your global variable. 
   liste = deckvalues
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Yours also worked. But can you explain it to me why when I called the variable 'deckvalues' in the second function it worked? I mean, I only called the variable deckvalues in the line 'lis = list(deckvalues.items())', not the entire function of cards().

Comment: Glad to hear that worked for you! And in the second function it is working because you are calling your global variable deckvalues which is being assigned form the cards function. However, this is going to be your pre-shuffled deck not post shuffled. also just realized your     deckshuffle = deckshuffle line is redundant as well. The line right above that is already setting your deckshuffle variable in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
liste = list(deckshuffle.items())
```

to this:

```
liste = list(shufflecards().items())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. But can you explain it to me why when I called the variable 'deckvalues' in the second function it worked? I mean, I only called the variable deckvalues in the line 'lis = list(deckvalues.items())', not the entire function of cards().